# Shared authorization between multiple CakePHP applications (multiple servers)?

Tags: cakephp

I need your help in this case.

Is there an easy way to share login information between two CakePHP 2.x apps on the same main domain but different sub-domain on multiple servers?

How can user logged in at A app, and B app know if a user is logged in or not.

Comment: I think you can achieves this using API integration .

Comment: like @u2460470 said. you can make your apps clients of their own api. please check how to setup rest api with cakephp. cookbook provides fantastic rest api docs <a http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your comment, I still stack with the logic to process this case. Would you please explain more details for me?